# Conditional PHP/Javascript Form Element

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, zen-cart

I have a question regarding a conditional statement for a new account form in Zen Cart.

I now have my form set to require the customer's Tax Identification Number (EIN) in the form of at least 9 characters, but I need this to be conditional ONLY if the country is set to the "United States" in the same form being submitted.

Any countries outside of the US should be able to apply for an account without entering an EIN.

Here is the javascript/php that checks the form:

```
<?php
/**
 * jscript_form_check
 *
 * @package page
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2010 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version $Id: jscript_form_check.php 16186 2010-05-03 18:38:57Z drbyte $
 */
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
var selected;

function check_form_optional(form_name) {
  var form = form_name;
  if (!form.elements['firstname']) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var firstname = form.elements['firstname'].value;
    var lastname = form.elements['lastname'].value;
    var street_address = form.elements['street_address'].value;

    if (firstname == '' && lastname == '' && street_address == '') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return check_form(form_name);
    }
  }
}
var form = "";
var submitted = false;
var error = false;
var error_message = "";

function check_input(field_name, field_size, message) {
  if (form.elements[field_name] && (form.elements[field_name].type != "hidden")) {
    if (field_size == 0) return;
    var field_value = form.elements[field_name].value;

    if (field_value == '' || field_value.length < field_size) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message + "\n";
      error = true;
    }
  }
}

function check_radio(field_name, message) {
  var isChecked = false;

  if (form.elements[field_name] && (form.elements[field_name].type != "hidden")) {
    var radio = form.elements[field_name];

    for (var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {
      if (radio[i].checked == true) {
        isChecked = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isChecked == false) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message + "\n";
      error = true;
    }
  }
}

function check_select(field_name, field_default, message) {
  if (form.elements[field_name] && (form.elements[field_name].type != "hidden")) {
    var field_value = form.elements[field_name].value;

    if (field_value == field_default) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message + "\n";
      error = true;
    }
  }
}

function check_password(field_name_1, field_name_2, field_size, message_1, message_2) {
  if (form.elements[field_name_1] && (form.elements[field_name_1].type != "hidden")) {
    var password = form.elements[field_name_1].value;
    var confirmation = form.elements[field_name_2].value;

    if (password == '' || password.length < field_size) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message_1 + "\n";
      error = true;
    } else if (password != confirmation) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message_2 + "\n";
      error = true;
    }
  }
}

function check_password_new(field_name_1, field_name_2, field_name_3, field_size, message_1, message_2, message_3) {
  if (form.elements[field_name_1] && (form.elements[field_name_1].type != "hidden")) {
    var password_current = form.elements[field_name_1].value;
    var password_new = form.elements[field_name_2].value;
    var password_confirmation = form.elements[field_name_3].value;

    if (password_current == '' ) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message_1 + "\n";
      error = true;
    } else if (password_new == '' || password_new.length < field_size) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message_2 + "\n";
      error = true;
    } else if (password_new != password_confirmation) {
      error_message = error_message + "* " + message_3 + "\n";
      error = true;
    }
  }
}

function check_state(min_length, min_message, select_message) {
  if (form.elements["state"] && form.elements["zone_id"]) {
    if (!form.state.disabled && form.zone_id.value == "") check_input("state", min_length, min_message);
  } else if (form.elements["state"] && form.elements["state"].type != "hidden" && form.state.disabled) {
    check_select("zone_id", "", select_message);
  }
}

function check_form(form_name) {
  if (submitted == true) {
    alert("<?php echo JS_ERROR_SUBMITTED; ?>");
    return false;
  }

  error = false;
  form = form_name;
  error_message = "<?php echo JS_ERROR; ?>";

<?php if (ACCOUNT_GENDER == 'true') echo '  check_radio("gender", "' . ENTRY_GENDER_ERROR . '");' . "\n"; ?>

<?php if ((int)ENTRY_FIRST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("firstname", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_FIRST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_FIRST_NAME_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>
<?php if ((int)ENTRY_LAST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("lastname", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_LAST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_LAST_NAME_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>

<?php if (ACCOUNT_DOB == 'true' && (int)ENTRY_DOB_MIN_LENGTH != 0) echo '  check_input("dob", ' . (int)ENTRY_DOB_MIN_LENGTH . ', "' . ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_ERROR . '");' . "\n"; ?>
<?php if (ACCOUNT_COMPANY == 'true' && (int)ENTRY_COMPANY_MIN_LENGTH != 0) echo '  check_input("company", ' . (int)ENTRY_COMPANY_MIN_LENGTH . ', "' . ENTRY_COMPANY_ERROR . '");' . "\n"; ?>
<?php if (ACCOUNT_EIN == 'true' && (int)ENTRY_EIN_MIN_LENGTH != 0) echo '  check_input("ein", ' . (int)ENTRY_EIN_MIN_LENGTH . ', "' . ENTRY_EIN_ERROR . '");' . "\n"; ?>
<?php if ((int)ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("email_address", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>
<?php if ((int)ENTRY_STREET_ADDRESS_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("street_address", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_STREET_ADDRESS_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_STREET_ADDRESS_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>
<?php if ((int)ENTRY_POSTCODE_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("postcode", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_POSTCODE_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_POST_CODE_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>
<?php if ((int)ENTRY_CITY_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("city", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_CITY_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_CITY_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>
<?php if (ACCOUNT_STATE == 'true') { ?>
  check_state(<?php echo (int)ENTRY_STATE_MIN_LENGTH . ', "' . ENTRY_STATE_ERROR . '", "' . ENTRY_STATE_ERROR_SELECT; ?>");
<?php } ?>

  check_select("country", "", "<?php echo ENTRY_COUNTRY_ERROR; ?>");

<?php if ((int)ENTRY_TELEPHONE_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_input("telephone", <?php echo ENTRY_TELEPHONE_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_ERROR; ?>");
<?php } ?>

<?php if ((int)ENTRY_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH > 0) { ?>
  check_password("password", "confirmation", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD_ERROR; ?>", "<?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD_ERROR_NOT_MATCHING; ?>");
  check_password_new("password_current", "password_new", "password_confirmation", <?php echo (int)ENTRY_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH; ?>, "<?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD_ERROR; ?>", "<?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD_NEW_ERROR; ?>", "<?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD_NEW_ERROR_NOT_MATCHING; ?>");
<?php } ?>

  if (error == true) {
    alert(error_message);
    return false;
  } else {
    submitted = true;
    return true;
  }
}
//--></script>
```

Would I be correct in assuming that somehow I need to add an conditional operator to state that if the country is set to the United States (zone_id 223), only then should the check should be executed for the EIN number?  Otherwise, leave it alone?

Thanks so much in advance :)

Here is the form code:  I feel like we are almost there, please forgive my ignorance...

```
    <?php
/**
 * Page Template
 *
 * Loaded automatically by index.php?main_page=create_account.<br />
 * Displays Create Account form.
 *
 * @package templateSystem
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2006 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version $Id: tpl_modules_create_account.php 4822 2006-10-23 11:11:36Z drbyte $
 */
?>

<?php if ($messageStack->size('create_account') > 0) echo $messageStack->output('create_account'); ?>
<div class="alert forward"><?php echo FORM_REQUIRED_INFORMATION; ?></div>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<?php
  if (DISPLAY_PRIVACY_CONDITIONS == 'true') {
?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRIVACY_CONDITIONS; ?></legend>
<div class="information"><?php echo TEXT_PRIVACY_CONDITIONS_DESCRIPTION;?></div>
<?php echo zen_draw_checkbox_field('privacy_conditions', '1', false, 'id="privacy"');?>
<label class="checkboxLabel" for="privacy"><?php echo TEXT_PRIVACY_CONDITIONS_CONFIRM;?></label>
</fieldset>
<?php
  }
?>

<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_COMPANY == 'true') {
?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo CATEGORY_COMPANY; ?></legend>
<label class="inputLabel" for="company"><?php echo ENTRY_COMPANY; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('company', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_company', '40') . ' id="company"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_COMPANY_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_COMPANY_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<label class="inputLabel" for="ein"><?php echo ENTRY_EIN; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('ein', '', 'id="ein"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_EIN_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_EIN_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
</fieldset>
<?php
  }
?>

<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_ADDRESS_DETAILS; ?></legend>
<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_GENDER == 'true') {
?>
<?php echo zen_draw_radio_field('gender', 'm', '', 'id="gender-male"') . '<label class="radioButtonLabel" for="gender-male">' . MALE . '</label>' . zen_draw_radio_field('gender', 'f', '', 'id="gender-female"') . '<label class="radioButtonLabel" for="gender-female">' . FEMALE . '</label>' . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_GENDER_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_GENDER_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<?php
  }
?>

<label class="inputLabel" for="firstname"><?php echo ENTRY_FIRST_NAME; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('firstname', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_firstname', '40') . ' id="firstname"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_FIRST_NAME_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_FIRST_NAME_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<label class="inputLabel" for="lastname"><?php echo ENTRY_LAST_NAME; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('lastname', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_lastname', '40') . ' id="lastname"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_LAST_NAME_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_LAST_NAME_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<label class="inputLabel" for="street-address"><?php echo ENTRY_STREET_ADDRESS; ?></label>
  <?php echo zen_draw_input_field('street_address', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_street_address', '40') . ' id="street-address"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_STREET_ADDRESS_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_STREET_ADDRESS_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_SUBURB == 'true') {
?>
<label class="inputLabel" for="suburb"><?php echo ENTRY_SUBURB; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('suburb', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_suburb', '40') . ' id="suburb"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_SUBURB_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_SUBURB_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<?php
  }
?>

<label class="inputLabel" for="city"><?php echo ENTRY_CITY; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('city', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_city', '40') . ' id="city"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_CITY_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_CITY_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_STATE == 'true') {
    if ($flag_show_pulldown_states == true) {
?>
<label class="inputLabel" for="stateZone" id="zoneLabel"><?php echo ENTRY_STATE; ?></label>
<?php
      echo zen_draw_pull_down_menu('zone_id', zen_prepare_country_zones_pull_down($selected_country), $zone_id, 'id="stateZone"');
      if (zen_not_null(ENTRY_STATE_TEXT)) echo '&nbsp;<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_STATE_TEXT . '</span>'; 
    }
?>

<?php if ($flag_show_pulldown_states == true) { ?>
<br class="clearBoth" id="stBreak" />
<?php } ?>
<label class="inputLabel" for="state" id="stateLabel"><?php echo $state_field_label; ?></label>
<?php
    echo zen_draw_input_field('state', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_state', '40') . ' id="state"');
    if (zen_not_null(ENTRY_STATE_TEXT)) echo '&nbsp;<span class="alert" id="stText">' . ENTRY_STATE_TEXT . '</span>';
    if ($flag_show_pulldown_states == false) {
      echo zen_draw_hidden_field('zone_id', $zone_name, ' ');
    }
?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<?php
  }
?>

<label class="inputLabel" for="postcode"><?php echo ENTRY_POST_CODE; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('postcode', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_postcode', '40') . ' id="postcode"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_POST_CODE_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_POST_CODE_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<label class="inputLabel" for="country"><?php echo ENTRY_COUNTRY; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_get_country_list('zone_country_id', $selected_country, 'id="country" ' . ($flag_show_pulldown_states == true ? 'onchange="update_zone(this.form);"' : '')) . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_COUNTRY_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_COUNTRY_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PHONE_FAX_DETAILS; ?></legend>
<label class="inputLabel" for="telephone"><?php echo ENTRY_TELEPHONE_NUMBER; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('telephone', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_telephone', '40') . ' id="telephone"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>

<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_FAX_NUMBER == 'true') {
?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<label class="inputLabel" for="fax"><?php echo ENTRY_FAX_NUMBER; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('fax', '', 'id="fax"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_FAX_NUMBER_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_FAX_NUMBER_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<?php
  }
?>
</fieldset>

<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_DOB == 'true') {
?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_DATE_OF_BIRTH; ?></legend>
<label class="inputLabel" for="dob"><?php echo ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('dob','', 'id="dob"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>
<?php
  }
?>

<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_LOGIN_DETAILS; ?></legend>
<label class="inputLabel" for="email-address"><?php echo ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('email_address', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_email_address', '40') . ' id="email-address"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<?php
  if ($phpBB->phpBB['installed'] == true) {
?>
<label class="inputLabel" for="nickname"><?php echo ENTRY_NICK; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('nick','','id="nickname"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_NICK_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_NICK_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<?php
  }
?>

<label class="inputLabel" for="password-new"><?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_password_field('password', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_password', '20') . ' id="password-new"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_PASSWORD_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_PASSWORD_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />

<label class="inputLabel" for="password-confirm"><?php echo ENTRY_PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_password_field('confirmation', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_password', '20') . ' id="password-confirm"') . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo ENTRY_EMAIL_PREFERENCE; ?></legend>
<?php
  if (ACCOUNT_NEWSLETTER_STATUS != 0) {
?>
<?php echo zen_draw_checkbox_field('newsletter', '1', $newsletter, 'id="newsletter-checkbox"') . '<label class="checkboxLabel" for="newsletter-checkbox">' . ENTRY_NEWSLETTER . '</label>' . (zen_not_null(ENTRY_NEWSLETTER_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_NEWSLETTER_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
<?php } ?>

<?php echo zen_draw_radio_field('email_format', 'HTML', ($email_format == 'HTML' ? true : false),'id="email-format-html"') . '<label class="radioButtonLabel" for="email-format-html">' . ENTRY_EMAIL_HTML_DISPLAY . '</label>' .  zen_draw_radio_field('email_format', 'TEXT', ($email_format == 'TEXT' ? true : false), 'id="email-format-text"') . '<label class="radioButtonLabel" for="email-format-text">' . ENTRY_EMAIL_TEXT_DISPLAY . '</label>'; ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>

<?php
  if (CUSTOMERS_REFERRAL_STATUS == 2) {
?>
<fieldset>

<legend><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_REFERRAL_DETAILS; ?></legend>
<label class="inputLabel" for="customers_referral"><?php echo ENTRY_CUSTOMERS_REFERRAL; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('customers_referral', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, 'customers_referral', '15') . ' id="customers_referral"'); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That is the same code as before..

Comment: What the... Sorry about that.  I have replaced.  Again, really appreciate this.

Comment: Hey @immulatin Sorry about the wrong code in the second part before.  Could you possibly offer some quick insight?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right, its a special case that requires its own check.

I would add another function to check the zone and then conditionally check the EIN:

Something like:

```
function check_ein(min_length, min_message, select_message) {
    if(form.elements["zone_id"] && form.elements["zone_id"] == 223)
        makeSureEINIsRightLength();
}
```

**UPDATE:** added solution code below

You need to add the check for the EIN (I added it below the country check):

```
    check_select("country", "", "<?php echo ENTRY_COUNTRY_ERROR; ?>");
    check_ein();
```

Then you need to add the javascript function to check the EIN:

```
function check_ein() {
    if(form.elements["zone_id"] && form.elements["zone_id"] == 223){
        var ein = form.elements["ein"].value;
        if(ein.length < 9){
            error_message = "EIN is less than 9 characters";
            error = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work other than I can't tell what the EIN field is on the form since it isn't included in the question. So will need to change "ein" on this line:

```
var ein = form.elements["ein"].value;
```

To the actually id of the EIN field.

Comment: Thanks immulatin.  I am a little green in this area, how would I implement this?  Thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: @cclark413 I updated the answer with a more comprehensive solution

Comment: I think I have a good idea now how to implement, however I don't think the variable for the country is correct of zone_id=223.  Any ideas?

Comment: That all depends on what the form looks like. You would need to change elements["zone_id"] to retrieve the value of the country code you are looking for. So maybe its elements["country"], I can't tell since there is no form code here.

Comment: I updated the question with the form code. Thank you soooo much for your help.  I really appreciate it.